# Updating to 12.10 failure

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, boot

I recently started using Ubuntu regularly, as it ran much more efficiently than Windows 7 which I'd been using before. I'm not the most knowledgeable person when it comes to computers, so I can't go into detail about what went wrong, as I don't fully understand, so let me try to explain step-by-step.

I had downloaded and installed Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit using the Wubi windows installer, and it ran just fine. I got all my files moved/copied over and 'set up shop' so to speak. After about a week, I tried to upgrade to 12.10, so I let the update go, making sure everything was closed, and checking yes to pretty much every box that came up. After I hit yes to the "Delete outdated files" option, or something along those lines, it was almost finished with the process when it asked me if I wanted to restart my system. I did. Then after booting up again, my screen just went black. In the top-left corner there was an underscore like I could type something, but it appeared to be frozen. I would greatly appreciate if someone could find out what went wrong, and hopefully tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid your problem is that you performed an in-place update. This is generally bad practice because so many things can go wrong. The user makes a lot of tweaks to Ubuntu over time (whether intentionally or not), so an in-place upgrade is generally hit or miss. For more information on that, look [here](http://www.dillonmorse.me/blog/posts/reasons-you-should-never-do-an-in-place-upgrade-of-your-os/).

I recommend performing a clean install, but with a seperate `/home` partition. That way, recurring clean installs will not cause you to loose your files. Be sure to back up before the install, so you don't loose anything important. For instructions on how to do that, look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202586/how-to-install-ubuntu-remove-mint-and-set-up-a-separate-home-partition).

Good luck!

Comment: Would there be any way to access my Ubuntu files through windows, just in case I accidentally erase them?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. Ubuntu uses a filesystem that Windows does not understand, so that won't work for you. Your best option is to make sure you don't touch the partion `/home` is on and make regular backups.

Comment: When I try to use the Wubi installer (Seemingly my only choice as I don't have a blank disc large enough, nor a USB stick available), it says I have to uninstall my current installation.

Comment: That's because wubi uses the Windows boot menu, and cannot work from GRUB2.